# Using javax.mail library for POPS with connect property "mail.pop3.filecache.enable" memory leak

Tags: java, email, pop3

I have configured this was to connect to POP3 mail server
on connect JAVA mail library creates temporary files when mail.pop3.filecache.enable = true
the message content will instead be cached in a temporary file. The file will be removed when the folder is closed. But on connect it calls file.deleteOnExit() which means it will be deleted when JVM shuts down .But in my use we do try to retrieve new messages every minute .
These temporary file stays in memory and cause high memory usage.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.filecache.enable",
                true);

        session = getSession(properties);
        store = new POP3Store(session, url);
        store.connect();
```

Comment: *"The file will be removed when the folder is closed"*. So are you closing the folder when done with it? Since [`Folder`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html) is an [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), you should really be using [**try-with-resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) with every `Folder` you get.

Comment: yes im closing the folder in Finally block , close calls the file.delete() but we still see the file reference in memory they grow every minute since this process never ends.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem with `deleteOnExit()`.  The API was not well thought out and is rather useless in long-running applications.  You will need to write your own cache management (or use one of the available libraries).  There is no "automatic" solution for this problem.